# Observable collection with List of object

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, observablecollection

Whether an observable collection can notify change of inside list ?

```
ObservableCollection<List<TimeSeriesData>> ChartLines = 
new ObservableCollection<List<TimeSeriesData>>();
```

And if i modify List whether it can notify changes ?

Comment: The `ObservableCollection` can notify you if _it_ changes. It can't tell you anything about any changes to the items it is holding.

Comment: @JeffMercado thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `INotifyPropropertyChanged` for your T object and for property that your `ObservableCollection` is representing:

```
 private ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> _myCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> MyCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _myCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _myCollection= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

You also need to implement `INotifyPropropertyChanged` for all members of `MyViewModel`:

```
 public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private string _myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get { return _myProperty; }
        set
        {
            _myProperty= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Addinionally you mustn't forget about UpdateSourceTrigger in XAML for MyProperty if you want to see updates on it run-time:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

I hope it will help you.